# How to get access to React and ReactDOM from browser console?

Tags: reactjs

I am just fiddling out in react.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
.... 
.... 

window.ReactDOM = ReactDOM;
window.React = React;
```

How do I get access to React and ReactDOM from the browser console?

The hack that i have used is attaching 'window' object for now. I know it doesn't seem right.Any better way to get this done. Cheers !

Answer (score 1):

You can use React Developer Tools, a chrome extension.
You can use it to inspect components, change state and props, inspect corresponding html elements and some more

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi